# Refresh dynamic inventory during playbook run

Tags: amazon-web-services, dynamic, ansible, inventory

Is it possible to refresh inventory during ansible playbook execution?

I create AWS objects (VPC, subnets, security groups etc.) from scratch with playbook which uses plugin `amazon.aws.aws_ec2` for dynamic host inventory.

When I run playbook, instances do not exist yet. Later I want to connect to freshly created instances, but ansible does not know about them.

I can run two playbooks consecutively in a script, then second one would query AWS and see instances, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your hosts are created by your playbook, run the following task before using them elsewhere in a consecutive play:

```yaml
- name: Refresh inventory from existing sources
  ansible.builtin.meta: refresh_inventory
```

Reference: [Ansible `meta` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html)